# SQL statement data insertion

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I have an sql statement, where im trying to insert data into the .mdb database, into a table. my query is

```
"INSERT INTO PROJECT_MASTER VALUES ('" + Project_ID.Text + "','" + Project_Name.Text + "'," +
                          "'" + Common_Log_ID.Text + "','" + Common_Log_Description.Text + "'," +
                          "'" + Convert.ToString(Project_Manager.SelectedItem) + "','" + Convert.ToString(Priority_value) + "'," +
                          "'" + Convert.ToString(Complexity_value) + "','" + Convert.ToString(Status_value) + "'," +
                          "'" + Convert.ToDateTime(sd) + "','" + Convert.ToDateTime(ed) + "'," +
                          "'" + Notes.Text + "','" + Convert.ToString(User_Name) + "'," +
                          "'" + DateTime.Now + "')";
```

SO My table has 14 columns and 1st column is autonumber increment and last column is current date. Other than this I have given all the other correct only.

Im facing an error as "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same" in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

If you omit first column, than the query should be like that:

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT_MASTER (col2, col3, ..., col14) VALUES ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you two change two things in order to avoid such errors in general:

1.) List columns in INSERT

```
INERT INTO table (a, b) VALUES (1, 2)
```

This insets `1` into the column `a` and `2` into `b` and allows you to skip the first and the last column.

2.) Use [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa975744%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). This makes your statement more readable and also brings [some security](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 0):

because you are not giving `autoincrement` column value, database is getting only `13` values instead of `14`.

following way might help you....

```
"insert into PROJECT_MASTER(SPECIFY_COLUMN_NAMES_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO_INCLUDE_HERE) values(SPECIFY_YOUR_VALUES_HERE)
```

Comment: @saichandan you are welcome, and if it has solved your problem,then  you can accept the answer(any 1 of the 3 answers which is closed to your question)